# How can I trigger handle_generate_automatic_ticket jQuery function in WooCommerce thank-you.php page instead of manually generating a ticket number?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

EDIT* I have rewritten original question.

I am trying to force the Lottery for Woocommerce plugin on WordPress to auto generate ticket numbers in the thankyou page instead of manually doing this for every order in the WP dashboard.

I can't find the item ID of what is in the basket.

Latest error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: item_id is not defined
    <anonymous> https://www.unicorncompetitions.com/checkout/order-received/11073/?key=wc_order_02bCFA2GQQTa1&doing_wp_cron=1712209272.9610309600830078125000:2402
    jQuery 2
        e
        t
11073:2402:17
    <anonymous> https://www.unicorncompetitions.com/checkout/order-received/11073/?key=wc_order_02bCFA2GQQTa1&doing_wp_cron=1712209272.9610309600830078125000:2402
    jQuery 2
```

Here is my code I've got it down to:

```
        add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'generate_ticket_on_thankyou_page');
function generate_ticket_on_thankyou_page() {
    ?><script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

            var data = ({
                action: 'lty_generate_automatic_ticket_edit_order',
                item_id: item_id,
                order_id: $('.lty-order-id').val(),
                answer_id: $('.lty-question-answer-id').val(),
                lty_security: lty_shop_order_params.lty_automatic_ticket_nonce,
            });

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (res) {
                LTY_Shop_Order.unblock($('.woocommerce_order_items').find('#order_line_items'));
                if (true === res.success) {
                    alert(lty_shop_order_params.lty_success_message);
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    alert(res.data.error);
                }
            }
            );
        },
)});
        </script>
    <?php
};
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in a `<script>` tag inside of your `generate_ticket_on_thankyou_page` PHP function?

Comment: @disinfor how would I write this? I'm sure the code will need rewriting for this to work?

Comment: @disinfor hello, I've edited my post after trying to trigger via your suggestion

Comment: Okay, and now _what_ happens? So far, this is still missing an actual problem description. (And should you be tempted to just say "not working" now, please go read [ask] first.)

Comment: @CBroe does that make more sense now? The order is going through but the ticket numbers they ordered don't auto generate. I have to press a button in the WooCommerce backend that launches the auto generate ticket script.

Comment: Now you told us that it doesn't do what you wanted it to - that still doesn't give us any more useful info. What have you done so far to try and debug this? Have you verified that the JS code is actually present in the source code of the thank you page? Have you checked the console for JavaScript errors? Have you checked whether this AJAX request is actually happening? And if so, what response it got?

Comment: @CBroe sorry I should of mentioned this. The script is in the source code of the correct page. I think the issue is with finding the order ID

Comment: _"I think the issue is with finding the order ID"_ - no, your JS has syntax errors. `}, handle_generate_automatic_ticket: function (item_id)` - that `}` ends your $(document).ready callback function, and a comma coming after that, doesn't make much sense. It looks like you copy&pasted this out of some sort of larger JavaScript object, that had functions assigned as properties ...? The syntax could probably be corrected quite easily - but I doubt whether you even have a `LTY_Shop_Order` object available at this point?

Comment: @CBroe the LTY_Shop_Order is the from the original script within the plugin. The code works using document.click in it's original file. The LTY is the plugin abbreviation

LTY_Shop_Order is correct, this is for the WooCommerce product which is a Lottery product type

Comment: _"the LTY_Shop_Order is the from the original script within the plugin"_ - that doesn't necessarily mean it already exists when your code tries to run; or that it will be embedded into the thank you page at all. And the syntax would need fixing anyway.

Comment: @CBroe can you explain further please? Imagine I'm a baby :)